# When hashing password for storage generateHash method giving arrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, database, hash, salt

I'm attempting to hash a password for storage in a database, I keep getting an arrayIndexOutOfBounds error though.

I call `signup("Test","password")` and the output is Test 35.. can anyone point me in the right direction please, thank you!

```
public static void signup(String username, String password) {
    String saltedPassword = SALT + password;
    String hashedPassword = generateHash(saltedPassword);
    DB.put("username", hashedPassword);
}

public static String generateHash(String input){
    StringBuilder hash= new StringBuilder();
    try {
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] hashedBytes = sha.digest(input.getBytes());
        char [] digits = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
        for (int idx = 0; idx<hashedBytes.length; idx++) {
            byte b = hashedBytes[idx];
            hash.append(digits[(b & 0xf0)>>4]);
            hash.append(digits[b & 0x0f]);   //<<<<<<<------ Error on this line.
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hash.toString();     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing some hex digits so the array indexes (at expected length 16) fail. This

```
char [] digits = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
```

should include 7,8 and 9 like

```
char [] digits = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
        'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to a login page for a user in a web application, the only way I can figure out to do it is to perform the same hashing method to a password they enter and compare it to the stored one, if the entered password hash and stored password hash match then allow access... Do you think this would be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Your array index is going to be out of bounds. You're trying to access the 16th element of an array that holds only 13 elements.

I suspect you've simply missed 7, 8 and 9 from your digits array.

```
char [] digits = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
```